# Bookmark always to toolbar by default in Firefox 16

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

The question sounds easy but I could not find a solution using google search. Maybe you have an idea:

I am searching for the Firefox setting to bookmark always to the toolbar.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the default "Folder" is "Bookmarks Menu". I'd like to have it always "Bookmarks Toolbar", without the need of changing it every time.

[image]

PS: I know that you can use the mouse and drag the icon from the URL to the toolbar. But using the keyboard more and more as it is just faster, this is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I think in older versions of Firefox there was a Options setting somewhere for designatiing a default new bookmarks folder, but it appears to to be gone now. Nowadays I use the [Add Book Mark Here <sup>2</sup>](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-bookmark-here-2/) extension and don't miss not having the setting anymore all that much.

One of the many things is does is remember the last selected folder when you bookmark a page.